# Reading a Dialog Box in Python

Tags: python, win32gui

I am trying to automate a daily routine I do using Python. Using the win32gui library I have been able to put a cursor in a position, click, and sendkeys.  During this task, several message/dialog boxes pop up, asking yes or no, to certain questions.  I would like to be able to read the question in the message box , but have no idea how I will approach it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just to give you one possibility, you may be able to copy the full contents of a dialog box to the clipboard by sending a `Ctrl-C` with sendkeys while focus is on the dialog.  The contents of the clipboard will generally look something like this:

```
[Window Title]
Rename

[Content]
If you change a file name extension, the file might become unusable.

Are you sure you want to change it?

[Yes] [No]
```

`win32clipboard` from the `pywin32` library allows you retrieve the contents of the clipboard so you can parse the text and respond, or do whatever else you need to do with it:

```
import win32con
import win32clipboard

try:
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    text = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData(win32con.CF_TEXT)
    print(text)
except TypeError:
    print('Error: No text on the clipboard!')
finally:
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

Unfortunately, there are some dialogs that can't be copied to the clipboard like this.  I couldn't tell you the reason, but the Delete Confirmation dialog in Windows 7 is one of them.